# How to get ethereum contract public variables?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I want to get `bool paused;` in my react application without transaction. It is implemented in myetherwallet.com contract gui. How can i do this? If possible i want to do this with mappings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the call method; it is evaluated directly on local node without sending transaction to the blockchain.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call/770#770